# Django Installed app and ImproperlyConfigured Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Actually, I am maiking a RabbitMQ consumer in Dango Project in the same directory as the **manage.py** file, i am facing the above error.

I also added

```
import os
import pika, sys, os, json
from matcher.views import GenerateOutput

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

These lines i got are from the stackoverflow related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are making 2 mistakes.

First: In the Code, you have to write those *os.enoviron* line above to the code line where you are importing the **views.py** function **GenerateOuput**

Second: You have to import the django in the code and  write the code line below
`django.setup()`

So the Complete Code will be :

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()
import pika, sys, os, json
from matcher.views import GenerateOuput
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ.setdefault()` only takes action when the environment variable isn't already set. That is, if DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is already set in your environment, and has a different value than what you need, this would explain your issue. Try using

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
```